# When I install packages, I keep getting fontconfig warning

Tags: vim, emacs, sublime-text

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a virtual machine, and I was installing packages, specifically text editors in this case (emacs23, sublime, vim..). Anyways, I get this massive warning of font configurations when I try to launch the editor after installing it.

```
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-khmer.conf", line 14: out of memory
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-khmer.conf", line 23: out of memory
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-khmer.conf", line 32: out of memory
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-garuda-synthetic.conf", line 9:
Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-garuda-synthetic.conf", line 21:
Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-kinnari-synthetic.conf", line 9:
Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-kinnari-synthetic.conf", line 21:
Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-loma-synthetic.conf", line 12:
Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-umpush-synthetic.conf", line 9:   
Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-umpush-synthetic.conf", line 21:   
Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 9: 
Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 22: 
Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 22: 
Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 22: 
Having    multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 26: 
Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 31: 
Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 40: 
Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
```

I'm new to ubuntu, so I don't really know what any of this means. If anyone could help diagnose this, and tell me how to fix it that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I analyse problem the solution is......

It is a bug in Khmer fonts, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-khmeros/+bug/1254967.

If it bothers you and you do not need Khmer fonts, you can get rid of it removing (with configuration) the fonts:

```
 apt-get purge  fonts-khmeros-core
```

If you need the fonts, there are various workarounds in the aforementioned bug. The most correct way seems to edit the failing file and remove the  and  tags, as explained here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.bugs.general/1095401